# Customer count with X products

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to get the count of partners having 1 product, 2 products, 3 products, 4 products, 5 products. They are all in one table.

```sql
SELECT #COUNT(user), #
COUNT(1) AS Service,
CASE WHEN product IN ('x') THEN 'x' 
     WHEN product IN ('y') THEN 'x' 
     #WHEN product IN ('z') THEN 'z' 
END AS Product
FROM table
GROUP BY user,product
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  Please post your table layout, the data for the table, and the results from the query you posted.

Comment: Do you have any question about this query?